# Delete rows with duplicate values and include NAs as individual values

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a df like this:

```
testdf <- structure(list(POS = c(37, 44, 50, 83), Col1 = c("A", "C", NA, 
"G"), Col2 = c("A", NA, "T", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

which looks like that:

```
     POS  Col1 Col2
[1,] "37" "A"  "A" 
[2,] "44" "C"  NA  
[3,] "50" NA   "T" 
[4,] "83" "G"  "C"
```

And i would like to exclude all rows which are the same between Col1 and Col2 (that means only row 1). Unfortunately i do not know how to deal with the NAs. When i try

```
testdf[testdf$Col1 != testdf$Col2,]
```

it does not consider NAs as an own entry?

The expected output should be:

```
     POS  Col1 Col2
[1,] "44" "C"  NA  
[2,] "50" NA   "T" 
[3,] "83" "G"  "C"
```

I would rather not transform NAs into something else.

```
testdf %>%
  rowwise %>%
  filter(Col1 != Col2)
```

Is also not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `is.na()` to your filter condition.

You should also handle the case where both columns are `NA`; I added a row like this to your example data. If you want to keep these rows, then:

```
library(dplyr)

testdf %>%
  filter(is.na(Col1) | is.na(Col2) | Col1 != Col2)
```

```
  POS Col1 Col2
1  44    C <NA>
2  50 <NA>    T
3  83    G    C
4  99 <NA> <NA>
```

If you want to remove them, use `xor()` instead of `|`:

```
testdf %>%
  filter(xor(is.na(Col1), is.na(Col2)) | Col1 != Col2)
```

```
  POS Col1 Col2
1  44    C <NA>
2  50 <NA>    T
3  83    G    C
```

Answer (score 2):

`NA == NA` returns `NA` but `NA %in% NA` returns `TRUE`. So you can use that in a `mapply` call to do rowwise comparison:

```r
testdf[!mapply(`%in%`, testdf$Col1, testdf$Col2),]

  POS Col1 Col2
2  44    C <NA>
3  50 <NA>    T
4  83    G    C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
testdf[testdf$Col1 != testdf$Col2 | is.na(testdf$Col1 != testdf$Col2), ]

# Or more concisely
testdf[with(testdf, Col1 != Col2 | is.na(Col1 != Col2)), ]


#   POS Col1 Col2
# 2  44    C <NA>
# 3  50 <NA>    T
# 4  83    G    C
```